# How to correct predicate CoreData Fetched property for Chat and Messages weak relationship?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a simple chat with typically relations chat and messages.

Chat entity have property chatId - type Integer

Message entity have property chatId - type Integer

In chat entity i created a fetched property (messagesFP) with simple (i think) predicate

```
chatId == $FETCH_SOURCE.chatId
```

[image]

I have chat with Id = 1, and messages which property chatId = 1.

But messagesFP - return empty array.

If i change predicate to

```
chatId == 1
```

So messagesFP return correct messages.

So, how to write correct predicate to fetch messages for current chat?

Comment: You question is too broad.

Comment: Why? Give link to example please.

Comment: You didn't share your code.

Comment: Why code? It's all. It's screen parameter fetchedProperty. No code.

Comment: Ok, i will add.

Comment: Have you tried using SQLDebug to see exactly what SQL statement is being generated when you access the fetched property?

Comment: @DmitryNelepov Hi, just wondering if you were able to try the solution below, and if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

If $FETCH_SOURCE points to an `NSManagedObjectID` on your end, you might want to try using the category below to correct that.

Here is a great reference in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html).

This is one of those convenience methods that we developers must provide on our end. In your project, replace `some_moc` with your managed object context.

```
@implementation NSManagedObjectID (FetchSource)

- (id) valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {

    //Attempt to unwrap the underlying object from the moc
    NSManagedObject *mocObject = [some_moc objectWithID:self];

    return [object valueForKey:key];
}

@end
```

I hope that works for you!